# Oracle Apex 4.2 custom file download error 404 Not Found or 403 Forbidden

Tags: blob, oracle-apex, oracle12c

I'am using Oracle Apex and I have a form to upload and store a file in a table via **wwv_flow_files**

In order to download the file I am using the procedure [download_my_file](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/appdev.32/e13363/up_dn_files.htm#CHDCGIEF)

When I try to click the link and download the error 404 is raised

My environment is

Application Express 4.2.6.00.03

Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Oracle Rest Data Service 3.0.9.348.07.16

Thanks to any suggestion or advice

**EDIT:**
I check the stored procedure in Apex going *Home->SQL Workshop->SQL Commands* 
If I copy and paste the code and instead of the parameter I use a known ID the execution is successful.

With the syntax **download_my_file?p_file=#ID#** url is

```
http://myhost:8080/ords/download_my_file?p_file=24255
```

the error **404 Not found** is raised.

With the syntax **#OWNER#.download_my_file?p_file=#ID#** url is

```
http://myhost:8080/ords/mypdb.download_my_file?p_file=24255
```

the error **403 Forbidden** is raised.

**EDIT 2 :** as requested here is the procedure

```
PROCEDURE download_my_file(p_file in number) AS
    v_mime  VARCHAR2(48);
    v_length  NUMBER;
    v_file_name VARCHAR2(2000);
    Lob_loc  BLOB;
BEGIN
    SELECT files_mime_type, files_content, files_name, dbms_lob.getlength(files_content)
            INTO v_mime,lob_loc,v_file_name,v_length
            FROM pub_db0files
            WHERE files_id = p_file;
          --
          -- set up HTTP header
          --
                -- use an NVL around the mime type and 
                -- if it is a null set it to application/octect
                -- application/octect may launch a download window from windows
                owa_util.mime_header( nvl(v_mime,'application/octet'), FALSE );

            -- set the size so the browser knows how much to download
            htp.p('Content-length: ' || v_length);
            -- the filename will be used by the browser if the users does a save as
            htp.p('Content-Disposition:  attachment; filename="'||replace(replace(substr(v_file_name,instr(v_file_name,'/')+1),chr(10),null),chr(13),null)|| '"');
            -- close the headers            
            owa_util.http_header_close;
            -- download the BLOB
            wpg_docload.download_file( Lob_loc );
end download_my_file;
```

Comment: You're probably not referencing the actual id column of your table. Can you edit your question to show your procedure and the table you are referencing?

Comment: @RLOG: I edited the question adding the full code used. Thanks.

Comment: Is the column you are referencing in your report called id?  My guess is that it's called `<something>_id` and you are not actually referencing it, hence it doesn't give you a number and you get a 404.

Comment: @RLOG: the url generated is myhost:8080/ords/download_my_file?p_file=24255 and for each row of the report the value of 24255 change correctly

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation «Fusion Middleware User's Guide for mod_plsql» regarding to `wpg_docload.download_file` we have to «add the line `WindowsFileConversion Off` to DAD entry.

> 1. Open the file ORACLE_INSTANCE\config\OHS\ohs1\mod_plsql\dads.conf.
> 2. Locate the DAD used to access the application.
> 3. Add the line `WindowsFileConversion Off` to this DAD entry.
> 4. Save the file.
> 5. Restart Oracle HTTP Server.
>
> If you do not update the DAD configuration, you will experience failures while downloading documents which contain 0x5c in the filename. For example:
>
> - In Oracle Portal, you will see the download error:
>
> `Error: Document not found (WWC-46000)`
>
> - When using mod_plsql against your own PL/SQL application, file downloads will result in the error:
>
> `HTTP-404 Not Found`

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/portal.1111/e12041/concept.htm#YPMOD001